# Multiple MODULEPATH entries in .modulesbeginenv

Tags: linux, environment-variables, command

I'm switching between paths/code projects. At each place I have different modules. To handle this there is a setup script that modifies what to use. This is handled with the tool 'module'.

**NOTE:** [`modules`](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) is a package for managing the environment allowing it to be reconfigured so that various applications are present on the `$PATH` or not.

Problem is that each time a module path is updated a new entry is added to the file `~/.modulesbeginenv`

```
#!/user/bin/env tcsh

module unuse $path1
module use $path2

module add project_module
```

This short example adds two lines to `~/.modulebeginenv` at each call. First `MODULEPATH='paths'` without `$path1` and then `MODULEPATH='paths'` with `$path2`.

It seems strange to me that the change is appended instead of updated. Is there any configuration to control this or any other way to solve it?

Comment: That depends on what this `module` program does. It isn't a standard command.

Comment: When I've used `modules` in the past that's been pretty much my experience with how it works. It augments the environment variables.

Comment: `module` comes from the Environment Modules project: http://modules.sourceforge.net/

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil'  It *is* a 'standard' command.  Often used on clusters and/or where development and regression tests on multiple development platforms going back years is done.  It would be difficult to work without it as it helps packages coexist.  It's been round since the 90's and uses the Tool Command Language (TCL) which is well known in the FPGA and ASIC manufacturing industries.  (TCL is my 2nd least favourite language after C#.  Imagine the power of Python but where there is only one type, string) See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_Modules_(software))

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the usage the behavior you're seeing sounds like what I would expect from the `use` sub-command.

> ```
>   module use [-a |--append] directory [directory...]
> ```
>
> By default, this subcommand prepends the directory to the `$MODULEPATH` environment variable. If the `-a` or `--append` argument is used, then the directory will be appended to `$MODULEPATH`.

With the sub-command `unuse` it will remove whatever path(s) you provide.

> ```
>   module unuse directory [directory...]
> ```
>
> Remove the directory from the $MODULEPATH environment variable.

If you want to completely override a variable you can always use the `setenv` command.

> ```
>   setenv variable value
> ```
>
> Set environment variable to value. The `setenv` command will also change the process' environment. A reference using Tcl's env associative array will reference changes made with the `setenv` command. Changes made using Tcl's env associative array will NOT change the user's environment variable like the setenv command. An environment change made this way will only affect the module parsing process. The `setenv` command is also useful for changing the environment prior to the `exec` or `system` command. When a modulefile is unloaded, `setenv` becomes `unsetenv`. If the environment variable had been defined it will be overwritten while loading the modulefile. A subsequent unload will unset the environment variable - the previous value cannot be restored! (Unless you handle it explicitly ... see below.)....

#### References

- [Modules User Guide](http://www.afrl.hpc.mil/docs/modulesUserGuide.html)
- [modulefile documentation](http://modules.sourceforge.net/man/modulefile.html)

Comment: The problem is not the append or prepend of `$MODULEPATH`, but that `$MODULEPATH` will be repeated, appended with its new content, to `.modulesbeginenv`. `.modulesbeginenv` will continue to grow until the system is restarted.